# Leapfrog method

Tags: numerical-methods

How do I use leapfrog method for a non-separable force ?

I know how to use it for the force of the form $f(q)+g(p)$. But I don’t know how to use it for the force like $f(q)\cdot g(p) $.

Comment: Please explain your variables and the use of the word "force".

Comment: @LutzLehmann it’s like q_dot = p and p_dot = func(q,p).  I know what to do if func(q,p)= f(q) + g(p) but I don’t know what to do if func(q,p) = f(q)*g(p).   (Also I want to solve the coupled system without combining two equations)

Comment: So you do $q_{n+1}-q_n=hp_{n+1/2}$ and $p_{n+1/2}-p_{n-1/2}=hf(q_n)·g(0.5*(p_{n+1/2}+p_{n-1/2}))$ and recognize that the second is now an implicit equation. You could also look into the Numerov method, order 4 for a similar effort.

Comment: @LutzLehmann actually the problem is functions f and g are mess and that’s why I wanted to avoid implicit method.